# How to push a Wordpress Plugin into store.wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, plugins, store

Is it possible to push your self coded  Wordpress Plugin into the official Wordpress store? I did not find anything about that process.

I just can't imagine that it's closed and only serviced by wordpress.com itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to publishing a plugin and maintaining it?

If so, there are more information here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_Submission_and_Promotion

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just found it here. Did not find it with Google though ...

https://wordpress.org/plugins/add/